# How to use bcrypt decoder in Spring security OAuth2 client?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have a spring boot application using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`. I want to hide my client secret in the application configuration file like :

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: service-a
            # this works
            client-secret: f4585c52-d30d-4247-b252-bfe61646efb0
            # this does not work
            client-secret: '{bcrypt}$2a$10$Q3FMa0KqtROryjqhjXlzueLGzfnQBb.OGp17AO.i/Bs3T9s7CqqBO'
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-authentication-method: BASIC
```

When I use `{bcrypt}` I get:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationException: [invalid_token_response]
An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response:
401 Unauthorized: [no body]] with root cause
```

Is it possible to do so ? And if yes what configuration should I add to make it work ?
I already tried to add the `BCryptPasswordEncoder`bean without any success.